# I'm trying to get posts under a custom taxonomy but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

Im using the following php. and I'm only trying to call titles at the moment. I have 4 posts under this taxonomy.

```
    <?php 
            $shopPosts = array(
                'post_type' => array( 'shop' ),
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'textiles',
                                'field' => 'term_id',
                                'terms' => 32,
                            )
                        )
            );
            $shopPage = new WP_Query( $shopPosts ); ?>
            <?php while ( $shopPage->have_posts() ) : $shopPage->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php end_while; ?>
```

Comment: Does `var_dump( $shopPage );` display any posts? Does `$shopPage->the_title()` display the title(s) you're expecting to see?

Comment: What’s up Pat, thanks for getting back to me. I'll check. currently, no titles are being displayed. and 32 is the id of textiles.

Comment: @PatJ could i use 'cat' => 32 in place of tax_query? I found that answer somewhere else and tried it but it didnt really change anything. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `'cat' => 32` wouldn't work for you, since that would look in the built-in `category` taxonomy, not your custom one. Your code snippet looks correct to me, assuming there are published `shop` posts that have term 32 in the `textiles` taxonomy applied to them.